# Simple ways for declaring value python

Tags: python-3.x, list, variables

I have 3 variables of array so i created

```
Indexlist = range(0, 9)
For i in indexlist:
    A = [i for i in indexlist]
    B = [i for i in indexlist]
    C = [i for i in indexlist]
```

So is there any simple way to declare?

Answer (score 2):

You can also make a copy of your list:

```py
from copy import copy

Indexlist = list(range(0, 9))

A = copy(Indexlist)
B = copy(Indexlist)
C = copy(Indexlist)
```

Doing this, modifications on one of these 3 lists will not affect the other ones

Answer (score 1):

Use this code. `A, B, C = [range(1, 10) for x in range(3)]`

Note that range(1, 10) is not list but generator. 
If you want the list, use this.

`A, B, C = [list(range(1, 10)) for x in range(3)]`

Comment: Why do you suggest using `range(1, 10)` instead or `range(9)`? These two ranges are different.

Comment: I know they are different. It is a just example.

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
A, B, C = [list(range(9)) for _ in range(3)]
```

or:

```
A = list(range(9))
B = list(range(9))
C = list(range(9))
```